# android AR view, why the speed of AR view is becoming slower

Tags: android, performance

I draw the constellation line in the AR view of android device. using the following code. At beginning ,the response speed of objects in AR view is ok. After I closed the AR view or left the AR view, and reopen or back to the AR view. The response speed of objects(constellations) in AR view became slower(may take it 1 second). How to deal with this issue and speed up. lenght1 = 352, length2 = 384. how to improve the performance.

By the way, after I uninstall the app, and run the app again, the response speed of objects in AR view become the normal.

```
     private void drawConstellationLine(Canvas canvas, int displayHeight,
        int displayWidth) {
    int length;
    float ex = 0, ey = 0, bx = 0, by = 0;
    Paint pline = new Paint();
    pline.setColor(Color.RED);
    double time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int i,j,length1,length2;
    for( i = 0, length1 = ShowMoon.starlinelist.size(); i<length1;i++)
    {
        for( j = 0, length2 = ShowMoon.starlist.size(); j<length2;j++){
         //System.out.println("length2:"+length2);

        if(ShowMoon.starlinelist.get(i).beginhr ==ShowMoon.starlist.get(j).hr) {            

                bx = (float)ShowMoon.starlist.get(j).x;
                by = (float)ShowMoon.starlist.get(j).y;
        }
             if(ShowMoon.starlinelist.get(i).endhr ==ShowMoon.starlist.get(j).hr) {
                ex = (float)ShowMoon.starlist.get(j).x;
                ey = (float)ShowMoon.starlist.get(j).y;

             }  
            }
      if (((bx >= 0 && bx <=displayWidth) ||( ex >= 0 && ex <= displayWidth))
       && ((ey >= 0 && ey <=displayHeight) || (by >= 0 && by <= displayHeight))){

        canvas.drawLine(bx, by, ex, ey, pline);
        //
        double time2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("time dif:"+(time2-time1));
        }
    }
```

these two codes: if(ShowMoon.starlinelist.get(i).beginhr ==ShowMoon.starlist.get(j).hr).
 if(ShowMoon.starlinelist.get(i).endhr ==ShowMoon.starlist.get(j).hr) 
take a lot of time.

Comment: If you want more information about, please tell me!

Comment: I have solved the issue. I load the database in activity. Actually, each operation will reload the activity, and then every time will reload the database. Just load the database at the beginning.and deleted the static. Thanks! I just share my comments.